# Dropping table identity causes ORA-00600 error on Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My Oracle DB version is 12.1.0.2.0.

I'm having a hard time removing the column identity. Also tried to drop the column and dropping the table with purge command, but every time I'm getting the same Oracle error:

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12811], [96650], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Just can't touch the identity column. I tried below commands but no luck:

```
ALTER TABLE DYS_CATEGORY MODIFY CATEGORY_ID DROP IDENTITY;

ALTER TABLE DYS_CATEGORY DROP COLUMN CATEGORY_ID;

DROP TABLE DYS_CATEGORY PURGE;
```

I can drop any other column from the table, but the problem is with **identity column**.

***Identity columns are new to Oracle, just introduced in 12c.***

Comment: Identity columns are just introduced in 12c. I'm not talking about columns with primary keys, those are different things. So you can not get this case in Oracle 11g. Btw I didn't mention anything about views...

Comment: ok friend, maybe i'm wrong.  Do you use RAC? I think you'd better contacting with Oracle for ORA-00600 type errors.

Comment: We are running our DB on a dedicated windows machine, not using RAC. It seems like an Oracle bug. This is the third bug I've spotted on 12c so far.

Comment: Dear citizen, we're also using the same version of Oracle for our production system with RAC, and we have lots of ORA-00600 errors, i suppose those error could be limited for Release 2 ... I don't know, just suppose.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I'll try to contact a DBA from our data center. I'll share the results if I can.

Comment: Steps to reproduce would be interesting, although I appreciate you might not know how the column/table/identity got into this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Oracle 12.1.0.2.0. At least one other person has [reported it (on Windows, which may be relevant)](https://emoracle.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/ora-00600-with-arguments-12811-154970/).

The error you have is an ORA-00600, which is Oracle's default message for unhandled exceptions i.e. Oracle bugs. The correct answer is to raise a Service Request with Oracle Support; they will be able to provide you with a patch or a workaround if you have a corrupted table you need to fix. If you don't have a Support contract you may be out of luck.

For future reference dropping `identity` columns is a two-stage process:

```
alter table t42 modify id drop identity;

alter table t42 drop column id;
```

As it happens, this is not a problem on the very latest version of the product. In Oracle 18c we can just drop the column without modifying it first. [LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/oracle_livesql/s/gaesymt4ho6zbjfycdsfupp8a).

Comment: I set up a test on my laptop (Oracle 12.2) using the steps on the linked blog, and `alter table xxx modify yyy drop identity` fails with the same ORA-00600.

Comment: From tracing the session for the `drop table purge` command on my (disposable) laptop DB, the corruption seems to be that `sys.idnseq$` still has the old object id for the now nonexistent sequence, and the `drop table` code doesn't have any handling for the case where it doesn't exist. Obviously deleting that row without being told to by Oracle Support would breach any support agreement and risk permanently breaking the database, so the answer as you say is to raise an SR.

Answer (score 1):

As William said above it looks like there is/was a system generated the sequence for the identity column that was deleted but the record in `idnseq$` remains intact.

I would not recommend this to anyone, but I created a new sequence called junk in the same schema.  I then found the `object_id` for the table and the sequence I created and updated `idnseq$` manually changing the `seqobj#` to the `object_id` of my new sequence for the object# of the table in question.

I was then able to drop the table and purge the recyclebin successfully.

Really don't recommend hacking oracle system tables, but this was a test system that didn't really matter and it worked.

Comment: From experimentation, it looks like the second argument in the ORA-600 error is the object ID of the missing sequence. I get `ORA-600 [12811] [98615]`, and `idnseq$.seqobj#` for the failing object is 98615.

Answer (score 0):

after lots of search and hard work if the table stil showing error ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:

Do the below step.

1. Take a backup of original tables
   syntax: `Create table original_table_back as select * from original_table;`
2. Rename original table to some new table name
   syntax: `Rename original_table to original_table_1;`
3. Rename backup to the original table
   syntax: `Rename Original_table_back to original_table.`